# How to login as dasusr?

Tags: linux, terminal, db2, ubuntu-14.04

I have installed `DB2` on `Ubuntu 14.04`. First step says we should login to linux machine using either the DB2 Administration Server user ID (dasusr1 by default) or the DB2 instance user ID (db2inst1 by default).

But how to login as dasusr?

P.S. I am new to Ubuntu don't know much about commands beforehand.

Comment: This belongs on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can login by switching user

**su dasusr1**

In db2 10.1, i think the das server is started by default
Hope this helps,

thanks